# Using TypeScript transpiled code utilizing es6-style classes with imports in a browser without an additional transpilation step?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I use `target:"es5"` to transpile TypeScript code that uses es6-style classes & React, my intended entry point (here a file called `App.ts`) has transpiled code that looks like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var react_1 = require("react");
var react_router_1 = require("react-router");
```

When that first line in this snippet gets hit, I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` error. A similar issue is described on TypeScript's GitHub Issues pages [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685).

The [quick answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685#issuecomment-300008605) is that `exports` will exist in an environment that supports class loading.

> commonjs means there's an exports variable available. You can't run commonjs code directly in a browser.

Here's my html wrapper:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="./components/App.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script>
      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement('App', null),
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would appear ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41621235/1028230), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841682/write-typescript-and-emit-a-library-for-browser-and-node/32856076#32856076), [3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685#issuecomment-300008605)) that the usual response is to put *an additional transpilation step* between your TypeScript and its release to a client on a browser. Wait, what? I need to transpile the transpiled code? This kinda smells like one of those "[I thought the dishwasher washed the dishes](https://www.ispot.tv/ad/wPDf/cascade-platinum-lets-your-dishwasher-be-the-dish-washer)" commercials.

Another recommendation is to use a module loading library like RequireJS or SystemJS ([1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685#issuecomment-305999092), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2743#issuecomment-92943381)). That makes sense, but I haven't seen an example of adding a module loading lib to TypeScript compiled code for delivery to a browser. And, again, it seems like TypeScript could've intelligently (as in "with minimally duplicated code") included such a lib when it was transpiling.

(It also seems like RequireJS is at least conventionally used with a [different syntax](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/) with `require` where you `require(['lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3'], function (lib1, lib2, lib3) {...}})` rather than the simpler `var lib1 = require('lib1')` TypeScript is producing, though [perhaps I'm missing something](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule)?)

So at least two related questions here:

1. What's the expected use case for the `target="es5"` TypeScript transpiled code?
2. How does one deliver es6 TypeScript code to the browser without transpilation steps beyond what TypeScript can do?

   - That is, is there a `platform:"browser"`-style setting I've missed?
   - If not, should RequireJS work with the code TS has produced? How should that be "bootstrapped"/started?

---

**UPDATE:** (Moving my comments from @felixmosh's answer into the question)

I have tried adding `"module":"es2015"` to my tsconfig.json, but the code started lighting up with errors on lines like this: `import Home from './pages/Home';` that read `error TS2307: Cannot find module './pages/Home'`.

My impression was that the `module` option defined the way modules are *defined* in the TypeScript rather than how they'll be *transpiled* in the resultant JavaScript code. That is, if this option only affected output, why would my untranspiled code throw errors once the module setting is added/changed rather than simply change the resulting JavaScript files' syntax?

@felixmosh also [helpfully] suggests using something like [RollUp.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en), but that does an end run around loading modules by, well, it *says* compiles, but it's really just *conglomerating* "small pieces of code into something larger and more complex". Putting all the modules into one file is sort of cheating. (Though why doesn't TS at least do this conglomeration?)

So +1 to felix & thanks for the help, but I still don't understand why TS stops where it stops -- What's the use case for the code it does produce? Does TypeScript really *require* a step outside of TS to use es6-style classes in code delivered to browsers?

**Why do I care?** I've worked with RequireJS based codebases before, and it is nice to have your files broken out in a way that you can debug more easily than a monolithic codebase. But I also don't understand why TS seems like it doesn't produce deployable code in this use case.

Comment: Just a small note: You can skip all the BS setup in the future by using the typescript-directed `create-react-app` `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `import/export` of es6 you should define `module:"es2015"`, by default, it converts those to cjs style that is used within node.

[Modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) are no supports node's `cjs` style but `es2015` style, so you need to specify that module type, and specify on your script tag an attribute of `type="module"`, something like that:

```
<script type="module" src="entry-point.js"></script>
```

Currently there is a native support of **modules** only in chrome, therefore these days the best practice is to create a *bundle* from the dependency tree that you have created using *imports*.

The common boundlers are [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) & [RollUp](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en), you can read their configs in-order to generate bundle that runs in browsers.

Small ref for typescript & webpack config: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out, if that won't explain the think, i will be happy to explain farther.

Comment: There is no native support for loading modules in the browser (except in Chrome), so Babel / TS won't be able to transpile something that requires browser support for.

Comment: Think about that, you have 2 files, a.ts that has dependency on b.ts, there is no code that you can generate that will make the browsers to start the run from a.ts, understand that it requires b.ts, download it first, execute it, and only then execute a.ts... you must have browser support for that.

Comment: But isn't loading dependencies [*exactly* what RequireJS does](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html#2)?

Comment: RequireJS is an implementation that was made by lib, you are suggesting that TS will transpile es6 import syntax to requirejs... and then you will need to include that lib?

Comment: BTW, there is `amd` value for the module property, so TS can generate code as RequireJS consumes, more info https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#code-generation-for-modules

Comment: Yep, I *think* that last comment & link are discussing *exactly* what I'm asking. Or at least half of it. I still don't understand the use case for the code TS is producing now -- it's a superset of JS but *also* includes a downgrading transpilation step. What JS platform is `target:"es5"` really targeting? But I just swapped to `module:"amd"`, and that looks really promising. Thanks!

Comment: TS as a concept, is a super set of JS, it allows you to annotate types.
Beacuse they transpiles the code to remove / valid those types they added es-next features... and transpiled them to es5... but it is not his main concern :]

Answer (score 1):

I see you are getting started with building TypeScript web applications. If so this is my advice:

Transpiling TypeScript to JS is unavoidable,

Don't use  RequireJS or SystemJS and instead use a bundler tool like parcel, webpack, rollup, browserify. Particularly I recommend **parcel** since is super easy and plays nice with TypeScript

- With a bundler, get rid of all those those defines() requires() SystemJs.calls() and use just standard JavaScript import declarations (import {foo} form 'bar'). I strongly recommend this too
- BTW avoid using require.js, AMD, UMD, SystemJS or similar. Is not a good advice getting started using those. Only use them if really really necessary.

Good luck