# Can I use typescript directly on Google Chrome (without trans-compiling to javascript)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This test.html page fails on Google Chrome (April 2019, Version 73.0.3683.86)

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
const str: string = "hello";
alert(a);
</script>
</body>
```

It complains with
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`
This shows that Google Chrome does not understand typescript.

I tried also with `<script type="application/ecmascript">`, but I get the same error.
Can I use typescript directly on Google Chrome (without trans-compiling to javascript)?

Comment: "Can I use typescript directly on Google Chrome" No. Google Chrome (like all major browsers) has a JS engine, not TS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use typescript in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620921/how-to-use-typescript-in-browser)

Comment: @CoderPi The question you linked is not the same. In yours, the person asking seems to have trouble transpiling, because they transpile into a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not. The browser has a JavaScript engine and not a TypeScript engine. TypeScript has to be compiled to JavaScript, you can use Source Mappings to show the TypeScript when you inspect it.